# Rails: Why is POST request submitted to main URL here (/users)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest

I am on second chapter of [Rails Tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/toy_app) by Michael Hartl.

When I do this :

```
rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string
```

This is what my `users_controller.rb` looks like:

```
  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /users/new
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /users/1
  # PATCH/PUT /users/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/1
  # DELETE /users/1.json
  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: 'User was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

When I go to `http://localhost:3000/users/new`, I get a page for adding new user but when I check where the request for the new user is being submitted, sure enough it's POSTed to `/users`. 
[image]

Why is the new user submitted to `/users` as opposed to `/users/new` ? Is this some sort of convention ? I created another scaffold and it behaves the same way. I've worked with Flask before and I added my POST request code to the same method/function which accepted my GET request. Why is this not the case here ? Couldn't Rails just send my new user POST request to `/users/new` ? And why`/users` URI in particular ? This is confusing me. Any link would be awesome. Thank you!

**Quick Edit**: Something I missed to add. Is this because I shouldn't think of these URI as URI but some kind of abstract entity I submit to. For example, when I add a new user, adding to users (`/users`) the entity would make more sense than adding to `/users/new` ? If I use this logic, the PUT method submitting to `/users/id` makes more sense since I am submitting to an existing user entity as opposed to a URI.

Comment: `/users/new` is a set for GET request, by which you are able to see new user form. Now as you submit the form, it will request to `create` action which is POST `/users`. nothing is wrong with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a convention.

You might want to read about [Representational State Transfer (REST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) - especially the part about the [relationship between URL and HTTP methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Relationship_between_URL_and_HTTP_methods).

Comment: Thank you! This answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

Run `rake routes` from terminal and you will see all routes of the app.

Below are the routes for users:

```
HTTP Verb   Path            Controller#Action
GET         /users              users#index
GET         /users/new          users#new
POST        /users              users#create
GET         /users/:id          users#show
GET         /users/:id/edit     users#edit
PATCH/PUT   /users/:id          users#update
DELETE      /users/:id          users#destroy
```

`/users/new` called `UsersController` with `new` action and fetch `new.html.erb` which contains a form with `POST` request and action be `/users`.

After form submit, 'UsersController' with `create` action is called which creates new user.

So,

GET `/users/new` => Its a get request which display a page with form

POST `/users` => Its a post request which create user.

For more details on rails routing check link http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Thanks @puneet18 ! I have checked that link before asking this question. My question was, why POST to `/users` and not to `/users/new` ?

Comment: @retrazil check rake routes

Comment: @retrazil I updated my post. There is all routes for users resources. Its rails convention, rails provides all these routes.

Comment: @retrazil `/users/new` is GET type request and called users controller with new action whereas `/users` POST request called create action